# Do package managers like NPM and Yarn affect watchers and executions?

Tags: javascript

There are package managers like NPM and Yarn. They handle the package installations a bit different.

When all the packages has been installed, does the package managers do anything more? When starting for example Vue with `yarn dev` or `npm dev` does the package managers do anything or are they just let the packages run?

What I'm really after is if the package installers affect the performance even after the packages has already been installed.

Does package installers affect the packages only on installation or all the time?

Comment: Are you asking about running a dev environment vs deploying to a production environment?   Can your question be paraphrased "Will installing a dev environment effect the performance of a production build an that machine?"

Comment: @StephenOstermiller No, that's not what I'm after. My question is whether or not the package managers only affect the performance when packages are installed OR if they also affect performance when packages run.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **web development** which is off-topic at Pro Webmasters. Web development questions may be asked at [so] but be sure to read their [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting to ensure your question meets their guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in performance between `yarn` and `npm` except during the package installation process(install, update, and remove). For watcher and executions it's depend on script and node JS version, So package managers like NPM and Yarn doesn't affect watchers and executions performance.